# Matplotlib polar plot is not plotting where it should

Tags: python, matplotlib

I try to represent spherical coordinates azimuth and elevation in degrees in a polar plot. I have a set of values to test for 0, 90, 180 and 270 degrees, and it is clearly seen that they are not plotted at the azimuth value they should.

Code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import rc, grid, figure, plot, rcParams, savefig


def generate_satellite_plot(observer_lat, observer_lon):
    rc('grid', color='#316931', linewidth=1, linestyle='-')
    rc('xtick', labelsize=15)
    rc('ytick', labelsize=15)

    # force square figure and square axes looks better for polar, IMO
    width, height = rcParams['figure.figsize']
    size = min(width, height)
    # make a square figure
    fig = figure(figsize=(size, size))

    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True, axisbg='#d5de9c')
    ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

    sat_positions = [[1, 30, 0], [2, 60, 90], [3, 30, 180], [4, 50, 270]]
    for (PRN, E, Az) in sat_positions:
        ax.annotate(str(PRN),
                    xy=(Az, 90-E),  # theta, radius
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc = 'green', alpha = 0.5),
                    horizontalalignment='center',
                    verticalalignment='bottom')


    ax.set_yticks(range(0, 90, 10))                   # Define the yticks
    yLabel = ['90', '', '', '60', '', '', '30', '', '', '']
    ax.set_yticklabels(yLabel)
    grid(True)

    savefig('foo.png')
```

And this is the result, clearly imprecise:
[image]

I have changed the axis so they start at 0 degrees and then go clockwise, and the radius represents the elevation (from 90º at the circle center, until 0º at the border).

Comment: This is not a case of degrees versus radians? I don't know mpl polar plots by heart, but since '1' is at the right angle, and the angles between consecutives satellite positions are the same (just not 90 degrees), it looks like it. Unless, of course, you're not talking about the angles being imprecise.

Comment: @Evert, you are correct. `theta` is in radians instead of degrees. Converting to radians with `degree * (pi / 180.)` will lead to the correct results.

Comment: You might also want to use `ax.set_yticks(range(0, 100, 10))` to make the `alt=0` (at `r=90`) tick show.

Comment: @Evert That's right. I can accept that as an answer if you insert as one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late, but:

Code:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import rc, grid, figure, plot, rcParams, savefig
from math import radians

def generate_satellite_plot(observer_lat, observer_lon):
    rc('grid', color='#316931', linewidth=1, linestyle='-')
    rc('xtick', labelsize=15)
    rc('ytick', labelsize=15)

    # force square figure and square axes looks better for polar, IMO
    width, height = rcParams['figure.figsize']
    size = min(width, height)
    # make a square figure
    fig = figure(figsize=(size, size))

    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True, axisbg='#d5de9c')
    ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

    sat_positions = [[1, 30, 0], [2, 60, 90], [3, 30, 180], [4, 50, 270]]
    for (PRN, E, Az) in sat_positions:
        ax.annotate(str(PRN),
                    xy=(radians(Az), 90-E),  # theta, radius
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc = 'green', alpha = 0.5),
                    horizontalalignment='center',
                    verticalalignment='center')


    ax.set_yticks(range(0, 90+10, 10))                   # Define the yticks
    yLabel = ['90', '', '', '60', '', '', '30', '', '', '']
    ax.set_yticklabels(yLabel)
    grid(True)

    savefig('foo.png')
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generate_satellite_plot(Az,El):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)
    ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
    ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
    ax.plot(np.deg2rad(Az),90-El,'*')
    ax.set_yticks(range(0, 90+10, 30))                   # Define the yticks
    yLabel = ['90', '60','30','0']
    ax.set_yticklabels(yLabel)
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, np.pi*2, np.pi/2))                   # Define the xticks
    xLabel = ['N' , 'E','S','W']
    ax.set_xticklabels(xLabel)
    plt.show()


Az=[90, 180, 270]
El=[20, 30, 10]
Az= np.array(Az)
El= np.array(El)
generate_satellite_plot(Az,El)
```

[The output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68935.png)

Comment: Please add some explanations to your code so that it is useful for OP and anyone facing the same problem.